# Azure Resource Manager Template parameters from Environment variables

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I'd like to use an environmentvariable as a parameter. Is this possible? This way I'd like to make my resources unique in name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, this is not directly possible, however you can use powershell\bash\whatever to achieve that dynamically

Comment: I found that you can give the parameters on the command line of azure cli.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using azure devops you can override your parameters file with `overrideParameters` 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-resource-group-deployment?view=azure-devops

alternatively use something like `envsubst` and a script step before you deploy your pipeline